# How to change color of command prompt, only the first line?

Tags: bash, command-line, colors, prompt

[image]
I want to change color of the main command line. Just the first and last ones. 
The command I've called and the prompt line that waits to new command. 
When I've called a command and it returns some stuff, I'm lost in those! I want to highlight the main line and the new line. 
If I can reposition the main line it would be great too!
I'm not sure if it's clear enough, sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You want to color the `PS1` variable. You can't color the output of `cat`

Comment: `export PS1="$(echo -ne "\e[1;33m$PS1\e[0m")"` might work just to colorize the prompt without changing its content.

Comment: As a funny alternative you can have a kind of colored cat using colored grep : `grep --color '.*' file`

Comment: @DopeGhoti That would only work if there are no backslashes in `$PS1`, which is unlikely.

Comment: @StephenRauch That thread only explains how to colorize the prompt, not how to colorize the command line.